# Kubernetes - add multiple lines to yaml configuration file based on

Tags: yaml, text-processing, yq

I have **kube-apiserver.yaml** file that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 192.168.49.2:8443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=192.168.49.2
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,NodeRestriction,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=8443
    - --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    - --service-account-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/sa.pub
    - --service-account-signing-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/sa.key
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --tls-cert-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver.key
    image: registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.3
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 192.168.49.2
        path: /livez
        port: 8443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        host: 192.168.49.2
        path: /readyz
        port: 8443
        scheme: HTTPS
      periodSeconds: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 192.168.49.2
        path: /livez
        port: 8443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ca-certificates
      name: etc-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/lib/minikube/certs
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/minikube/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-share-ca-certificates
status: {}
```

and i created another file called **patch.yaml** based on kube-apiserver.yaml structure that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - --audit-policy-file=/etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
    - --audit-log-path=/var/log/kubernetes/audit/audit.log    

  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
      name: audit
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/log/kubernetes/audit/
      name: audit-log
      readOnly: false

  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
      type: File
    name: audit
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/log/kubernetes/audit/
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: audit-log
status: {}
```

I want to modify **kube-apiserver.yaml** so it looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 192.168.49.2:8443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=192.168.49.2
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,DefaultTolerationSeconds,NodeRestriction,MutatingAdmissionWebhook,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=8443
    - --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    - --service-account-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/sa.pub
    - --service-account-signing-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/sa.key
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --tls-cert-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver.key
    - --audit-policy-file=/etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
    - --audit-log-path=/var/log/kubernetes/audit/audit.log   
    image: registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.3
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 192.168.49.2
        path: /livez
        port: 8443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        host: 192.168.49.2
        path: /readyz
        port: 8443
        scheme: HTTPS
      periodSeconds: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
    startupProbe:
      failureThreshold: 24
      httpGet:
        host: 192.168.49.2
        path: /livez
        port: 8443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ca-certificates
      name: etc-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/lib/minikube/certs
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      name: usr-share-ca-certificates
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
      name: audit
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /var/log/kubernetes/audit/
      name: audit-log
      readOnly: false
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-node-critical
  securityContext:
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/minikube/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-local-share-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /usr/share/ca-certificates
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: usr-share-ca-certificates
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
      type: File
    name: audit
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/log/kubernetes/audit/
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: audit-log
status: {}
```

Basically what i want is to add commands from patch.yaml to kube-apiserver.yaml as well as volumeMounts and volumes.

Comment: I answered your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646311/how-to-combine-two-json-objects-using-jq/74647623#74647623) yesterday

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine two JSON objects using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74646311/how-to-combine-two-json-objects-using-jq)